# Jquery: get label content and set it as value

Tags: jquery, forms

Im trying to set the values of checkbox inputs automaticly by jquery. the value should be the label name. i tried it with this code but i didnt worked. whats wrong with it ?

```
$(function () {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').val($('label[for="'+$(this).html()));

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is the `document` and you need to iterate instances

You can use `val(function)` to do the iteration

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').val(function(){
   return $('label[for="'+this.id +'"]').html();
});
```